# How do I set up a fee for my p2pool node?

Tags: p2pool, dogecoin

I'm running a p2pool node for dogecoin.

Since running the node costs me some money, I set up a small fee with

```
./run_p2pool.py --give-author 0 --net dogecoin -f 0.5 -a DSomeDogeAddressIOwn DOGEUSER DOGEPW
```

but I don't seem to get any fees.
The local hashrate is around 10 MH/s, so I should get at least a few dogecoins.

Basically I used this setup: http://doges.org/index.php/topic,5586.0.html

It is running on an Ubuntu 12.04 Server, everything else works.
When I use the webinterface, "http://example.com:22550/fee" displays '0.5' as expected

Am I missing something?

Comment: You may want to add what software you are using to run the pool, with a link to it.

Answer (score 1):

Found out why I'm not seeing the fees:
The fee payouts are of type 'mined' so in the client history, they don't show up with an address.

http://dogechain.info/chain/Dogecoin/q/addressbalance/DMYSTUPIDADRRESS

Told me that there must have come some coins in.
Wow, such joy!

Edit:
seems like the new client shows to which address it was mined.